# Docker run ubuntu command failed with error : Error while pulling image:

Tags: docker, virtualization, ubuntu-16.04, http-proxy, docker-registry

Docker run ubuntu command failed with error :

> Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:48892->[::1]:53: read: connection refused.

Ubuntu version : 16.04
kernel version :- 4.4.0-59-generic

Docker Info:
Containers: 0

- Running: 0
- Paused: 0
- Stopped: 0

Images: 0
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: aufs

- Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
- Backing Filesystem: extfs
- Dirs: 0
- Dirperm1 Supported: true

Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:

- Volume: local
- Network: null host bridge overlay

Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-59-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 12
Total Memory: 15.62 GiB
Name: cran
ID: 2VRU:AMVJ:VEEZ:EVE7:6AOH:X57L:SX4L:MC5B:IE7X:267V:LPG7:KXRM
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:

- 127.0.0.0/8

Docker version :1.12.1

Comment: Can you give the command you're trying to execute ?

Comment: Does docker pull for the same image works fine ? Has the image been already pulled ?

Comment: Sryther : "Docker run ubuntu"  command failed.  Though this command is working fine " wget https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images".  Charles : Images is not pulled .Docker pull command is also giving same error as "docker run ubuntu". Point to note : I am working behind company proxy .